# hide element on certain state in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know how to describe the title, forgive me. But I'm seriously stuck on something. I'm practicing a todo list where u can do inline editing. **I'm stuck at hiding control buttons : edit and delete for a particular row when the state of isEdit for a particular row is present**.

http://jsfiddle.net/rsp61fmh/

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
     return {
       items:[1,2,3],
       isEdit: null
     }
   },
   renderEditForm(){
   return(
   <div>
   <input type="text" />
   <button onClick={this.saveHandler}>save</button>
   </div>
   )
   },
   ItemCtrl(index){

   return(
   <div className="itemCtrlWrap">
   <button onClick={this.editHandler.bind(this,index)}>Edit</button>
   <button onClick={this.dltHandler.bind(this, index)}>Delete</button>
   </div>
   )

   },
   editHandler(i){
   this.setState({isEdit:i})
   },
   saveHandler(){
    this.setState({isEdit:null})
   },
   dltHandler(index){
     this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter((item,i) => i !== index)})
   },
   renderItem(){
     return(
       this.state.items.map((item,i)=>
         <li key={i}> {this.state.isEdit==i ? this.renderEditForm() : item} {this.ItemCtrl(i)}</li>)
     )
   },
   render(){
      return(
        <ul>
          {this.renderItem()}
        </ul>
      )
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding condition to your `ItemCtrl` method like this may help :

```
   ItemCtrl(index){

   return index !== this.state.isEdit ? (
     <div className="itemCtrlWrap">
      <button onClick={this.editHandler.bind(this,index)}>Edit</button>
      <button onClick={this.dltHandler.bind(this, index)}>Delete</button>
   </div>
   ) : '';  
   },
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I missed that